# Ag-grid gridReady event not working in storybook

Tags: storybook, ag-grid-angular

I'm facing a issue with AG-grid in Storybook.
I'm trying to do filtration in AG-grid added as storybook template. But gridReady event doesn't get fired
Here is the code for reference
**someApp.component.html**

```
<div style="float: right; width: 100%;display: flex;    <=== this is dive to have search field. We can add input here. 
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;">
<mat-search-bar (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" (onClose)="clearFilter()" [placeholder]="Search"></mat-search-bar>
</div>                                                         <===== on keyup it takes the input from search field and get the filter data in AG-Grid

    </mat-toolbar>
    <div class=" ag-grid-container">
    <ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-material ag-grid-container"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [rowData]="rowdef"
        

[suppressColumnMoveAnimation]="true"
            [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true"
            [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        >
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

In the above code, I get the value of search and call applyFilter to set quickfilter in grid
**someApp.component.ts**

```
columnDefs = [
    { headerName:'Sports', field: 'sports'},
    { headerName:'No: of Players', field:'player'},
];
gridApi!: GridApi;
  Search = "Search";
onGridReady (params) {
    console.log('calling grid Api');
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    console.log('called grid Api: '+this.gridApi);
   
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  public overlayNoRowsTemplate =
   '<div *ngIf="rowDef.length === 0" class="no-records">No database found.</div>';

  applyFilter(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(
      value
    );
  }
  clearFilter() {
    this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(""
    );
  }
```

**someApp.stories.ts**

```
import {
  GridApi,
  GridReadyEvent,
  ICellRendererParams
} from 'ag-grid-community';
import { moduleMetadata, Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
import { ActionsComponent } from 'projects/web-component-library/src/lib/components/actions/app-actions.component';
import {someApp} from '../../projects/web-component-library/src/lib/components/inventory/inventory.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../projects/web-component-library/src/lib/components/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgMatSearchBarModule } from 'ng-mat-search-bar';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomActionComponent } from 'projects/web-component-library/src/lib/components/custom-action/custom-action.component';

const rowdef = [{sports:'Cricket', player:11},
{sports:'Basketball', player:5}
]

export default {
  title: 'Data Inventory',
  component: someApp,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [someApp,CustomActionComponent],
      imports: [MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule,NgMatSearchBarModule,AgGridModule.withComponents([CustomActionComponent]),RouterModule]
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;

export const Default = (args: someApp) => ({
  component: someApp,
  props: args
});

Default.args = {
  rowdef
};
export const NoData = (args: someApp) => ({
  component: someApp,
  props: args
});

NoData.args = {
  rowdef:[]
};
```

When I try to search something
it gives error as this.gridApi is undefined. whereas when I add this in parent HTML as below and run as 'ng serve', its works fine
**App.component.html**

```
<some-app><some-app>
```

Seems like onGridReady is not fired properly in storybook.

Using
Storybook 6.0.12
Angular 8
npm 6.13.4
node v10.19.0

Log of error in storybook

[image]